# How to retrieve value after added custom column in order details

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes, hook-woocommerce

I am not able to retrieve the value of measurement “volume” after I added custom column in order page details using below code:

```php
// Add custom column headers
add_action(
  'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers',
  'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');

function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() {

  //column name
  $column_name = 'Total M3';

  // display the column name
  echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

// Add custom column values here
add_action(
  'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 
  'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values',
  10, 
  3);

function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {

  // get the post meta value from the associated product
  $value = get_post_meta($_product->post->ID, '_custom_field_name', 1);

  // display the value
  echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
```

I am using [WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-measurement-price-calculator-developer-documentation/) plugin to calculate the measurement. I cannot find meta value.

Comment: get function to replace "_custom_field_name"

Comment: How have you saved the volume to the order? It strikes me that the volume is per product and not per order, but I'm not sure if the calculator function also creates a total.

Comment: I didn't add yet function to save value! the volume per product set on the backend and calculator shows on the front end (quantity*volume) as "value" which i need it to show on the backend order page

Comment: I cannot find the meta key (attribute) of the "WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator " plugin. this will help to save and show it on the back end

Comment: I think WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator has no hooks to add  meta item on admin order panel. And i found post attribute "_measurement_needed" & "_measurement_needed_unit" to generate volume value